# Calculating the number of unique combinations of genders of siblings in a triplet birth

Tags: probability

By unique I mean that (boy,girl,girl) and (girl,boy,girl) are the same,

of course when you write it down on a piece of paper you can solve this but I wanted to ask if anyone knows a formula that solves this kind of question when the number of items to choose from (boy or girl) is smaller than the number of choosing (3 babies).

The answer I got is 4 unique combinations:

(boy,boy,boy)
(girl,girl,girl)
(boy,girl,girl)
(boy,boy,girl)

Comment: So, you are looking for the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a,b≥0$ and $a+b=n$.  Since $b=n-a$ the pair is determined by $a$, so the answer is $n+1$.

Comment: When you have more than two types, the calculation is slightly more complicated but still perfectly doable.  The counting technique [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is designed specifically to handle those problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of ways to distribute $k$ balls (babies) over $n$ bins (genders), which is

$$
\binom{n+k-1}n
$$

(see e.g. [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) at Wikipedia).